# Encrypting secrets before passing it to dockerfile

Tags: docker, github, kubernetes

I have a dockerfile where I am trying to copy everything in Github to dockerfile and build it as an image. I have a file called config.json which contains sensitive user data such as username and password. This will also be copied. The issue here is, I want this data to be encrypted and passed onto the dockerfile. While the image is being deployed onto kubernetes, I want this data to be decrypted back again. Can anyone please suggest an ideal method of doing this.

Comment: Secrets should not be in the dockerfile or in the container at all. They should be provided at runtime using configmaps provided by K8s secrets - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't put this in the container image at all. Use a tool like Sealed Secrets, Lockbox, or sops-operator to encrypt the values separately, and then those get decrypted into a Secret object in Kubernetes which you can mount into your container as a volume so the software sees the same `config.json` file but it's stored externally.

Answer (score -2):

As other people have mentioned the *technically* correct way to do this is to treat secrets like ordinary config and have something external to the container doing the secret-fu to keep everything safe.

However sometimes you may be in a situation in which the the *technically* correct thing is not the *practically* correct thing and you need to deploy config and/or secrets in your artifact/docker image.

If you just need to encrypt a single file, generating a key and doing symmetric encryption using a tool like `gpg` may be the easiest way to go about doing this.

If you are encrypting many files or encrypting them frequently it may make sense to use asymmetric encryption to do so. In this case, PKCS7/cms may make sense and the `openssl` binary conveniently has a `cms` subcommand for encrypting and decrypting CMS content.

Comment: If you encrypt stuff, then you need to decrypt it again. You have exactly the same problem once removed.

Comment: Frequently it is easier to encrypt and deploy a single, smaller, secret rather than many larger ones. If this is the case in your environment then symmetric encryption or PKI with symmetric(CMS) can be a good way to go.

Ideally you have something like Vault or AWS Secrets Manager available to you, but sometimes you don't.